# How to do math on strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var string = "2+3-1";
document.write(string);
```

In the code above, I have a string with digits and plus and minus operators. I want to calculate the string when i want to display it. I mean, when i want to dispaly, it should calculate and show 4. I tried to convert them to number but gives error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built in method `eval()`

**Note:** Using `eval()` is never recommended. You should use some kind of external library like https://mathjs.org/

```js
var string = "2+3-1";
document.write(eval(string));
```

Comment: There should be a warning that this is VERY unsafe if the string is not hardcoded. For a safer alternative purely for doing math, a library like [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) should be used.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks. I added a note for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What causes that eval() is never recommended?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using plus and minus only, you might do something like this:

```js
var string = "2+3-1";
document.write(string);

var result = string.match(/([-+]?\d+)/g).reduce((a, e) => a- -e, 0);
document.write(' = ' + result)
```

Comment: Awesome! One question, how did you convert the string to number?

Comment: @EliasAchilles, What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, in the code above, you cannot do math on string. The variable result is still string and it shouldn't do the calculation, as long as i know. But it did.

Comment: @EliasAchilles, `var result` is a number calculated via `match` and `reduce` methods, not a string. Probably you're confused with the formatting of my code.